# $M = AA^t$ where $A$ has unit norm columns

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ positive definite with $\operatorname{tr} M = m$, where $m$ is an integer such that $m \geq k$. I have found a way (using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/280203/89544) answer) to decompose $M = AA^t$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ such that $A = (a_1, \dots, a_m), a_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\|a_i\|_2 = 1, i=1,\dots,m$.

1. Is there a name for such a decomposition? This is not Cholesky, although it looks similar.
2. Is this decomposition unique? We can always take $\hat{A} := AD$ where $D$ is a permutation matrix with $\pm 1$ entries. Then $\hat{A}\hat{A}^t = M$ and $\hat{A}$'s columns have unit norm. I am not sure if there is any other obstruction to uniqueness.
3. In my numerical experiments, I find that the some columns of $A$ are identical (up to a sign). Any reason for that?

## Example

Let $M =diag(1.5,1.5)$. One can verify that $M=AA^t$ for

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{3/4}& \sqrt{3/4}& 0 \\
-1/2& 1/2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
P.S. The assumption on the trace above is necessary because $\text{tr} M = \text{tr} AA^t = \text{tr}A^tA$ and $A^tA\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ has unit diagonal.

## Reference

Using Raphael's answer below I was able to find the reference:

Peter A. Fillmore, On sums of projections, Journal of functional analysis 4, 146-152 (1969).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  apart from positivity  the OP is imposing a limit on $\mid M \mid$ by $|a_i|_2=1$. so it is unlike that every arbitrary positive matrix $M$ can be decomposed in the way OP required. he actually impose a boundedness condition on M.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Positive semidefinite + trace=m defines a bounded set. Once one assumes positivity I don't see any obvious obstructions to that kind of factorization.

Comment: In item 2, when you say "unique", do you mean "up to replacing $A$ by $AC$ where $C$ is orthonormal"? (If not, the decomposition is heavily non-unique even for $m=k$ and $M = I_m$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg the rows of  A  and  AC have the same Euclidean norm not their columns. right?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  So according to your comment it is sufficient to prove the statement for diagonal positive matrix with integer trace. it is obvios when the entries are integer

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think we are having a misunderstanding --- I did not write anything in that direction. I merely observed that positive definite matrices with trace $m$ are a bounded set. I wrote nothing regarding diagonal matrices or change of bases.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Every positive matrix is diagonalizable via a uitary $U$ Now UAA^*U*$ works because the norms of columns of UA is the norm of columns of A, right. So we need to prove for diagonal case. it is obvious when each entry of diagonal is a positive integer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I don't know what you mean. What I'm saying is that if $m = k$ and $M = I_m$, then $A$ can be any orthonormal $m\times m$-matrix.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  I did not pay attention to I_m, I thought you say every arbitrary decomposition for m=k and arbitrary M is unchanged with unitary action that is AA*=AUU*A*, the later does not work but you are right for I_m

Comment: @FedericoPoloni yes, I forgot to write positive definite.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I need to stress that $A$ is $k \times m$, not $m \times m$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Regarding uniqueness - it is not unique because you can multiply by$D$ with $\pm 1$ diagonal. I am not sure if this is the only obstacle for uniqueness.

Comment: @YairDaon: I'm talking about the $m=k$ case.

Comment: What about $D$ a permurtation matrix?

Comment: @RaphaelB4 true! I'll modify accordingly.

Comment: And you can have both: a permutation matrix with $\pm 1$ entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This decomposition is equivalent to write $M$ as a sum of rank one orthogonal projection $$ M = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i a_i^* $$
with $\|a_i\|=1$. Indeed for any $x$ we have $$(Mx)_{s} = \sum_{i\leq m,t\leq k} A_{si}A^T_{it}x_t = \sum_{i\leq m} (a_i)_s \langle a_i,x\rangle
$$
Remark that in  form it is easy to see the invariance by permutation with $\pm 1$ entries and that $\text{Tr}(M)=m$.

We can consider the application $\phi:(\mathbb{S}^{k-1})^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, $\phi(a_1,\cdots,a_m)=AA^T=M$. Because $(\mathbb{S}^{k-1})^m$ is a manifold of dimension $m(k-1)$ and the subset of symetric matrices of trace $m$ is a manifold of dimension $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-1$. It is clear that we don't have unicity in the general case if $m> \frac{k^2+k-2}{2(k-1)}=\frac{k+2}{2}$.